# Blur effect on slider

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to create a slider with this effect: http://wowslider.com/bootstrap-carousel-example-shift-demo.html

have you any idea how to get it?

Comment: You can download and use that program.

Comment: Here is a codepen with the blur effect on a slider https://codepen.io/supah/pen/yePzKO

Answer (score 0):

OK, I find a free solution at http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/11/18/fullscreen-image-blur-effect-with-html5/

"The main idea is to add some images in our structure that will serve as background images."